# DDR2-DDR3 Co-mingle?

Tags: computer-building

I built a custom PC and installed 8gb ddr3 RAM to it, I also have a older desktop with 2gb DDR2 RAM in it and was thinking about putting that ram inside my new PC alongside my 8gbs DDR3, the frequencies are generally the same, or at least my mobo supports both frequencies. What's the con's (if any) about doing this? Should I just avoid this and spend a little extra cash ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, DDR2 and DDR3 [are completely incompatible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#cite_ref-5). While they have the same number of pins, the layout of the notch is completely different. You will have to buy the RAM which matches the notch layout on your motherboard.

Comment: You could sell your second hand DDR2 online and use the money to nearly pay for it probably. Please accept this answer if it has solved your problem.

Comment: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090720010559AA2h96Y

Comment: http://www.instructables.com/answers/Are-DDR2-RAM-chips-compatible-with-DDR3-slots/

Answer (score 0):

It probably won't work since DDR2 slots are different from DDR3 slots and most motherboards don't have both kinds of slots for the memory.

Comment: see my answer above.

Comment: @krowe There must have been a lag in the server because when I posted my answer, I only saw mine, and not yours.

Comment: Yes, I had a previous answer which I had  removed while I edited it.

Comment: @krowe BTW, here is a motherboard with both kinds of slots. http://www.asrock.com/mb/NVIDIA/N68C-S%20UCC/?cat=Specifications

Comment: Good to know that they exist.

Comment: I have a couple of these... http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5QC/ - they were used as transition machines - though, same as the asrock, they can do either/or DDR2/DDR3, not both simultaneously